# Retrieve dyamically inflated layouts to work with

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to dynamically add some ProgressBar views to an inflated layout from an xml file. I continue to get ClassCastExceptions when running the following code:

```
     // === This is the part I'm having trouble with ===
     ProgressBar v = (ProgressBar) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dayprogressbar, ll);
     ProgressBar p = (ProgressBar) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dayprogressbar, ll);
```

The code below is how it works without the casts and runs without error, but I need to work with the views as a progress bar. Is there any way I can do this without getting a ClassCastException

```
    /**
     * Pulls the layout from R.layout.listview and creates a single list
     * entry and returns it as a view to be put into the listview
     */
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // the view to be returned
        View itemLayoutView = convertView;

        // if the view doesn't exist, create the layout from the inflator
        if (itemLayoutView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // use listview.xml
            itemLayoutView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview,
                    null);

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.List_Main_LinearLayout_ProgressBars);

            // === This is the part I'm having trouble with ===
            View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dayprogressbar, ll);
            View p = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dayprogressbar, ll);


        }
```

Here is R.layout.dayprogressbar.xml that I'm inflating:

```
<ProgressBar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progress="50"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_horizontal"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
    android:minHeight="1dip"
    android:maxHeight="1dip"
    android:max="100"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
/>
```

Comment: i cant undrstnd ur need.you want to add progressbar in layout or want custom progressbar?

Comment: I've inflated an xml file, but I want to add 2 progress bars to a linearlayout inside the file. Here is where I pull the linearlayout out

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.List_Main_LinearLayout_ProgressBars);

and I want to add the progress bars to this layout, and then change the progress of the bars. To change the progress of the bars I need to work with the 2 inflated dayprogressbar.xml objects as ProgressBar objects not View objects, so I need to cast or convert them somehow. I Would like to know how to do it without getting exceptions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried these but, I'll post them anyway. :)

I have two opinions:

1) Cast v and p to progressbar since your R.layout.dayprogressbar.xml is a ProgressBar

```
ProgressBar v = (ProgressBar) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dayprogressbar, ll);
ProgressBar p = (ProgressBar) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dayprogressbar, ll);
```

I don't know if you can inflate two views and the same time.. Haven't done my homeworks lately.lol

2) You can inflate these views and just add it to ll

```
ProgressBar v = (ProgressBar) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dayprogressbar, null);
ProgressBar p = (ProgressBar) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dayprogressbar, null);
ll.addView(v);
ll.addView(p);
```

You might need to make some adjustments but at least I have given you some idea for a possible solutions.

Hope at least one of them works for you..

Comment: Options number works :D:D Getting some weird behavious from the LinearLayout though, as it seems to misinterprate the weights of it's objects. It already has 1 object with weight of '1' and these 2 being added have a weight of 1, but it seems to give the object already there 3/4 of the layout room =\

But thank you for fixing my question :)